# Self-hosted Azure Mobile Services

Tags: entity-framework, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

Is it possible to host an Azure Mobile Service? (Published on my own server)

I only want to use the Mobile SDKs to sync tables on mobile applications, I don't need push notifications.

I also want to have a Web API controlling this data in the same project, is it possible without having NuGet Packages problems?

Other question, do I need the Azure Mobile Backend to make it work with the Mobile SDKs (iOS, Android, etc)?

If those solutions don't work, I'll be hosting this on Azure and probably managing the data with another Web API self-hosted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider [Azure Mobile Apps](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/07/17/updates-to-the-mobile-apps-server-sdk/) which allows full control of your deployed site.

The Mobile Services backend, or Mobile Apps server SDK is required for the Azure Mobile client libraries to work.